# SpringBoot Application : CPU usage reaches to maximum just sometimes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, devops

How to troubleshoot/Optimize CPU usage in a Springboot application. Are the allocated resources sufficient for an application having a total of around a 300k user base? The application isn't heavy at all. It just calls third-party APIs and do the necessary checks and gives the response.
How to identify exact codes that could have been using more resources than normally required? I found out somewhere that tracking the processes id from top command and reaching to thread dump and looking up for the corresponding hexadecimal value of processid that could have been using more CPU is one way to figure out. This wasn't easily achievable as some of the commands suggested didn't work. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

[Htop command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rat67.png)

[Htop when it's normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2gfY.png)

Comment: Hi Sarjib, I think a JVM Profiler tool might help you find the cause of the resource or performance problem.  The JDK comes with a free Profiler.  This website can help you learn more about Profiler tools.  Good luck.   https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Answer (score 2):

The process of Collection of Thread Stack is no different for a spring boot app. Before a boot app is containerized it is still a Jar. If you suspect that its your application that is actually contributing to the high CPUT then run your jar and attach a profiler to it and trace the code contributing to the high CPU on load. If you can not do it then take the thread dump of the running jar/java process and use any free or opensource tool to analyze the trace. The second logic explained is applicable for the containerized application as well.

Follow this steps to take the thread dump of a java app/boot app running inside a docker container :-

```
docker exec -it <containerName> jstack > someFile.txt
```

Take multiple snapshot of it for better visiblity and comparision.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not added JMX enable options to the JVM commandline, do it to begin with:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=10000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then on your local machine you start "jmc" from your JDK bin folder and connect to your spring boot server.
You will then be able to see all the threads and enable both CPU load and thread locks on all active threads.

Be aware though that the above opens up JVM for unauthenticated entry so keep the port safe.

Next if your JVM dies send a "kill -3" SIGHUP which will tell the JVM to dump the core. that can then be read via the Eclipse MAT plugin in order to analyze the JVM inner doings.

Another way is to install jolokia into your server for other ways to retrieve the same info.